# Ada AUnit procedures Set_Up_Case and Tear_Down_Case called for each test

Tags: unit-testing, ada, aunit

I am making unit tests in an Ada application in an existing suite based on aunit. According to their [documentation](https://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/aunit/html/aunit_cb/aunit_cb/test_case.html#aunit-test-cases) and code, the procedures: Set_Up_Case and Tear_Down_Case should only run before the set of test routines. However, when I run the unit-tests (specific class or SmokeTests), then I see, they are run before and after each test. Stripped output:

```
2021-07-05 15:05:55 ----- Set_Up_Case -----                                                                             
2021-07-05 15:05:55 ----- Set_Up -----                                                                                                                                                                
2021-07-05 15:05:58 ----- Starting Test AAAA -----                                                              
2021-07-05 15:06:07 ----- Tear_Down -----                                                                               
2021-07-05 15:06:07 ----- Tear_Down_Case -----                                                               
           
2021-07-05 15:06:07 ----- Set_Up_Case -----                                                                             
2021-07-05 15:06:07 ----- Set_Up -----                                                                                                                                                                 
2021-07-05 15:06:10 ----- Starting Test BBBB  -----                                                                  
2021-07-05 15:06:34 ----- Tear_Down -----                                                                               
2021-07-05 15:06:34 ----- Tear_Down_Case -----
```

So how can I get the behaviour as documented?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Set_Up_Case` and `Tear_Down_Case` routines are run at the start and end of a *test case*. The `Set_Up` and `Tear_Down` routines are run before and after *a specific test routine within a test case*. This is best illustrated using the minimal example shown below. The example borrows quite some example code from the [AUnit cookbook](https://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/aunit/html/aunit_cb/aunit_cb.html).

**tests.ads** (a new *test case* that contains 3 *test routines*: `Test_A`, `Test_B` and `Test_C`)

```
with AUnit;            use AUnit;
with AUnit.Test_Cases; use AUnit.Test_Cases;

package Tests is

   type Test_Case is new Test_Cases.Test_Case with null record;

   procedure Register_Tests (T: in out Test_Case);
   function Name (T : Test_Case) return Test_String;
   
   --  Setup and tear down.
   procedure Set_Up (T : in out Test_Case);   
   procedure Set_Up_Case (T : in out Test_Case);
   
   procedure Tear_Down (T : in out Test_Case);   
   procedure Tear_Down_Case (T : in out Test_Case);   

   --  Test routines.
   procedure Test_A (T : in out Test_Cases.Test_Case'Class);
   procedure Test_B (T : in out Test_Cases.Test_Case'Class);
   procedure Test_C (T : in out Test_Cases.Test_Case'Class);
   
end Tests;
```

**tests.adb** (the implementation of the *test case* and its *test routines*)

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

package body Tests is

   ----------------------------------------------
   -- Test Case Name and Routine Registrations --
   ----------------------------------------------
   
   procedure Register_Tests (T: in out Test_Case) is
      use Test_Cases.Registration;
   begin
      Register_Routine (T, Test_A'Access, "Test A");
      Register_Routine (T, Test_B'Access, "Test B");
      Register_Routine (T, Test_C'Access, "Test C");      
   end Register_Tests;

   function Name (T: Test_Case) return Test_String is
   begin
      return Format ("Tests");
   end Name;
   
   -------------------------------
   --  Test Setup and Tear Down --
   -------------------------------

   procedure Set_Up (T : in out Test_Case) is
   begin
      Put_Line ("| Set_Up");
   end Set_Up;
   
   procedure Set_Up_Case (T : in out Test_Case) is
   begin
      Put_Line ("Set_Up_Case");
   end Set_Up_Case;
   
   procedure Tear_Down (T : in out Test_Case) is
   begin
      Put_Line ("| Tear_Down");
   end Tear_Down;
   
   procedure Tear_Down_Case (T : in out Test_Case) is
   begin
      Put_Line ("Tear_Down_Case");
   end Tear_Down_Case;
   
   -------------------------
   -- Test Routines A/B/C --
   -------------------------
   
   procedure Test_A (T : in out Test_Cases.Test_Case'Class) is
   begin
      Put_Line ("| | Test_A");
   end Test_A;
   
   procedure Test_B (T : in out Test_Cases.Test_Case'Class) is
   begin
      Put_Line ("| | Test_B");
   end Test_B;
   
   procedure Test_C (T : in out Test_Cases.Test_Case'Class) is
   begin
      Put_Line ("| | Test_C");
   end Test_C;

end Tests;
```

**a_suite.ads** (a new *test suite*)

```
with AUnit.Test_Suites;

package A_Suite is
   function Suite return AUnit.Test_Suites.Access_Test_Suite;
end A_Suite;
```

**a_suite.adb** (the *test suite* contains 1 *test case*: `Tests`)

```
with Tests;
     
package body A_Suite is
   use AUnit.Test_Suites;

   --  Statically allocate test suite:
   Result : aliased Test_Suite;

   --  Statically allocate test cases:
   Test_1 : aliased Tests.Test_Case;

   function Suite return Access_Test_Suite is
   begin
      Add_Test (Result'Access, Test_1'Access);
      return Result'Access;
   end Suite;
   
end A_Suite;
```

**main.adb** (the test driver)

```
with A_Suite;
with AUnit.Run;
with AUnit.Reporter.Text;

procedure Main is
   procedure Run is new AUnit.Run.Test_Runner (A_Suite.Suite);
   Reporter : AUnit.Reporter.Text.Text_Reporter;
begin
   Run (Reporter);
end Main;
```

**output**

```
Set_Up_Case
| Set_Up
| | Test_A
| Tear_Down
| Set_Up
| | Test_B
| Tear_Down
| Set_Up
| | Test_C
| Tear_Down
Tear_Down_Case

OK Tests : Test A
OK Tests : Test B
OK Tests : Test C

Total Tests Run:   3
Successful Tests:  3
Failed Assertions: 0
Unexpected Errors: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Seemed that my problem was that the original code explicitly ran each test in a separate process with certain settings.