# AUnit - Usefullness of the `Test_Caller` package

Tags: unit-testing, testing, ada, aunit

There seem to be two different ways to do the same thing when using the AUnit library:

Using the `AUnit.Test_Cases.Test_Case` type, creating some function tests, then register each tests with the `AUnit.Test_Cases.Register_Tests` function. We can then add this **Test_Case** to a **Suite** using the function `AUnit.Test_Suites.Add_Test`.

There some example of this:

- [the example of the cookbook](https://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/aunit/html/aunit_cb/aunit_cb/test_case.html#aunit-test-cases)
- [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68258400/ada-aunit-procedures-set-up-case-and-tear-down-case-called-for-each-test)
- [in the unit test of `AdaYaml`](https://github.com/yaml/AdaYaml/blob/develop/test/src/yaml-dom-dumping-test.adb)

(Surprisingly, there no examples using this way in the AUnit repository.)

The other way is to use the `AUnit.Test_Fixtures.Test_Fixture` type, creating some function tests. These tests can then be added to a **Suite** using the generic package `AUnit.Test_Caller` with the functions `AUnit.Test_Suites.Add_Test` and `AUnit.Test_Caller.Create`.

I can see way of using `Test_Caller` in:

- [the example of the cookbook](https://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/aunit/html/aunit_cb/aunit_cb/test_case.html#aunit-test-caller)
- [the examples AUint repo](https://github.com/AdaCore/aunit/tree/master/examples/test_caller)
- [in the unit test of `json-ada`](https://github.com/onox/json-ada/blob/fda3e8b1f56590c435077be0864e1ab63c52ace1/tests/src/test_images.adb)

The only difference I can see is that, when using the `AUnit.Test_Cases.Test_Case`, you can override the `Set_Up_Case`, `Set_Up`, `Tear_Down` and `Tear_Down_Case` functions. While with the `AUnit.Test_Fixtures.Test_Fixture` you can only override the `Set_Up` and `Tear_Down` functions (because the tests are not group under a **Test_Case**).

Appart from that, I don't really see much difference.

So, what is the use of the `AUnit.Test_Fixtures.Test_Fixture` type with the generic package `AUnit.Test_Caller` ? Why would use this over the (simpler ?) `AUnit.Test_Cases.Test_Case` type ?

Every example I have seen in one format can be transformed into the other (the `Set_Up_Case` and `Tear_Down_Case` set appart). Could give an example which use one but cannot be done by the other ?

Comment: See also [_7.2. OOP considerations_](https://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/aunit/html/aunit_cb/aunit_cb/test_organization.html#oop-considerations), which contrasts the two in the same context.